# What are the correct settings to get my website displayed via SSH local forward?

Tags: ssh

I would like to be able to access the website that runs on my server on my laptop (windows).

```
 +--------+       +----------+      +-----------+      +----------+
 | Laptop | <---> | Middle1  | <--> |  Middle2  | <--> |   Server |
 +--------+       +----------+      +-----------+      +----------+
```

My ssh configuration on my laptop looks like this:

```
Host server
    Hostname 192.168.102.2
    Port 444
    User server

Host middle2
    Hostname 192.168.0.121
    User middle2
    IdentityFile D:\Users\...\id_rsa
    ProxyCommand ssh -A middle1@172.112.228.23 -i D:\Users\...\key.pem -W %h:%p
    LocalForward 8600 mywebsite.de:443
```

With 'ssh middle2' I can log in to the second jump server 'middle2'. From here I can call up the website accordingly and it is displayed (on the console).

I also entered the following in my etc/hosts file on the laptop:

```
127.0.0.1 mywebsite.de
localhost mywebsite.de
```

I would like to be able to call up the website itself via mywebsite.de:8600 on my laptop.

Unfortunately, I am currently getting the error message that the page cannot be reached. Apparently my SSH configuration doesn't fit yet.

Could you tell me which settings I have to correct in order for my project to succeed?